# deleting a file from AWS cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have created a Cloudfront Distribution in AWS using S3 Bucket. 
I have uploaded some files in S3 bucket and provided the public readonly file permission to all the files. 
I can see all the files using the cloudfront server URL.

I want to delete some files from the cloudfront. I have deleted those files from the S3 bucket, and run the Cloudfront Invalidation also to delete the files from edge servers immediately. but the files are still there. I can access those files form the cloudfront URL. The files are there in the edge servers even after the TTL.

Can someone pls tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!